# Is a CD's coupon a fixed percentage of the invested amount paid upon maturity, or pro-rated? Is the rate annualized?

Tags: bond-coupons

For a non-callable CD with a maturity of 90 days, would an 8% coupon result in a payment of  the invested amount multiplied by 1.**02**? That is, is the stated coupon rate always an annualized rate, so that 8% per annum is 2% for a 3-month CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - coupons are reported as annualized, and are reported as the periodic coupon times the number of periods per year, so a 3-month CD with an 8% coupon would pay a 2% coupon.

Note that a quoted APY might be different since it would take compounding into effect, but the annualized interest it quotes would not.